# Meteor path length when using electrify

Tags: meteor, npm

When I package an app for windows using electrify, the npm dependencies have path lengths that exceed the 260 character limit imposed by Windows.

I've tried using "flatten-packages", but still no success.

How can I reduce the path lengths without breaking the app? At this point any solution is welcome - even a manual one.

Comment: What Meteor and npm versions are you using? See [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7221) thread.

Comment: I was using meteor 1.3.3.1 with the default integrated npm (2.15.1 ?) Now I'm installing npm@3 and will try again, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I tried packaging after installing npm@3, the path lengths are still as long as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you delete the `node_modules` dir? You can try Meteor v1.3.4.

Comment: Oh, I did not. Good point. I'm updating to 1.3.4 now, will keep you updated. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: This worked! Using Meteor 1.3.5.1 and deleting the node_modules has rebuilt them to reach a longest file path of 153 characters, which leaves sufficient breathing room. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to MasterAM - you need to update both the electrify dependencies and meteor's npm. For posterity, these are the required steps:

1) meteor npm install -g npm@3 (deep dependency problem has been fixed with npm v 3)

2) meteor remove arboleya:electrify

3) npm install -g electrify-updated-test (this is an unofficial updated version of electrify with new dependencies)

4) remove any node_modules folder from your project + .electrify folder

5) meteor update (this updates to 1.3.5.1 - the deep dependency problem has been fixed since 1.3.4)

6) electrify package